# Custom nameservers for dedicated hosting

Tags: nameserver, dedicated-server, 1and1

I have a high end dedicated server and will be using this to host around 3 to 4 client websites.

How can I give them a custom nameserver address?

EG: 1and1 says that the nameservers have to be ns54.1and1.co.uk and ns55.1and1.co.uk

Can I setup ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com and then set the A record for each to the actual IP address of ns54.1and1.co.uk and ns55.1and1.co.uk?

Will above work? What is the easiest way to setup a custom nameserver name?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If he is reselling

Comment: Even if you're not reselling, it looks a lot more professional if you're a SAAS provider, or work in the IT industry where people are likely to be whois'ing you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you hosting your own DNS server?

I will assume you have 2 IPs on your server, hosting DNS for your clients. If 1and1 is hosting the DNS for them, you would need to coordinate this with them, because if they change their IPs then it would bring your client's sites down.

If you are hosting your own DNS, you can do it one of two ways. The first way is to simply create a nameserver record at the registrar with the same IP addresses that are running the nameserver. This would allow their nameservers to show in the whois for the domain.

The second, better and more 'private' way to do this is to run your nameserver on separate ips, one for each nameserver you wish to create. You then create the A and PTR records for those IPs/Name servers. This ensures that anyone who would do some 'digging' would only find that company on that IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is Yes/No,

It depends on 1&1 dns settings.

If they allow sharing of IP's for name servers your ok, just setup A records in your domain.
If it is your own dedicated server you can host your own dns, and use the correct settings.

Answer (score 1):

That would kinda work, until 1and1 decide to move the nameservers onto different IP addresses - after all, IP addresses are just addresses. You would want to also adjust the SOA record to avoid issues about authoritative answers.

If your dedicated server has multiple IP addresses, you could install the nameserver of your choice, and manage the zones yourself, without needing any intervention from 1and1 (As it happens, this is the approach I used to take, although I now have separate machines for primary and secondary DNS)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a Vanity Name Server, and most major DNS hosting companies will happily provide this service for you.

They will give you the instructions on how to set up a [Glue record](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/ns.html) for your domain name (which is required for resolving the DNS). This often requires the assistance of your registrar as well.

We use [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/) - you can find [their tutorial here](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/s0306/tuts/vanitydns.html). It should work for other providers, but as mentioned, you will need their co-operation. Your DNS provider is very unlikely to be changing the IP addresses of their nameservers.

You will still need to set up A records in your DNS to point to the 'real' DNS servers.